# Simple CSS style - positioning div's

Tags: css, positioning

[image: The style wanted]

This is a really simple question about CSS. I want to get the style depicted in the picture, I tried this code:

```
#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
text-align:center;
}
.navbar {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:3px;  
}
.logo {
float:left;
}
.table {
float:left;
}
```

but it doesn't work for me, I get this: [image: not this!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#parent {
overflow: hidden;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
width:80%;
}
.navbar {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
right:3px;  
}
.logo {
float:left;
}
.table {
float:left;
}
```

In order to accomplish what you want, you'll need to center your parent divider using `margin:auto` and placing a fluid width using `width:80%`.

Comment: Hello, this is working for the table and the logo, but the navbar is not in line with the table.

Comment: I solved it with body { margin: 0 0 0 0; }, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd give your parent element an explicit width, then position from there:

```
#parent {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 3px;
}

.logo {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.table {
   width: 100%;
 }
```

I don't know what other contents you have on the page, but your .logo element *should* appear where you want using default HTML flow. If the table is 100%, it will clear. You should be able to pull this off without floats.